# Php mail body not encoded correctlly

Tags: php, email

I have a wev site with a form for sending emails. Unfortunatelly today i got e-mail from a client but the message body was unreadable because it couldn't display cyrilic symbols properly.

Here is the php code:

```
<?php
$owner_email = $_POST["owner_email"];
$headers = 'From:' . $_POST["email"];
$subject = 'Имате съобщение изпратено през формуляра на вашия WEB сайт от ' . $_POST["name"];
$messageBody = "";

if($_POST['name']!='nope'){
    $messageBody .= '<p>Visitor: ' . $_POST["name"] . '</p>' . "\n";
    $messageBody .= '<br>' . "\n";
}
if($_POST['email']!='nope'){
    $messageBody .= '<p>Email Address: ' . $_POST['email'] . '</p>' . "\n";
    $messageBody .= '<br>' . "\n";
}else{
    $headers = '';
}
if($_POST['state']!='nope'){        
    $messageBody .= '<p>State: ' . $_POST['state'] . '</p>' . "\n";
    $messageBody .= '<br>' . "\n";
}
if($_POST['phone']!='nope'){        
    $messageBody .= '<p>Phone Number: ' . $_POST['phone'] . '</p>' . "\n";
    $messageBody .= '<br>' . "\n";
}   
if($_POST['fax']!='nope'){      
    $messageBody .= '<p>Fax Number: ' . $_POST['fax'] . '</p>' . "\n";
    $messageBody .= '<br>' . "\n";
}
if($_POST['message']!='nope'){
    $messageBody .= '<p>Message: ' . $_POST['message'] . '</p>' . "\n";
}

if($_POST["stripHTML"] == 'true'){
    $messageBody = strip_tags($messageBody);
}

try{
    if(!mail($owner_email, $subject, $messageBody, $headers)){
        throw new Exception('mail failed');
    }else{
        echo 'mail sent';
    }
}catch(Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage() ."\n";
}
?>
```

I am new to php so the question is:

What should i change in this code to make it work with cyrilic format?

Comment: may be encoding like UTF-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this after your `$headers = ...` line:

```
$headers .= "\n".'MIME-Version: 1.0'."\n".'Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8";'."\n".'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit';
```

Comment: What is the difference between 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit' and 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit'?

Answer (score 0):

try

`$header .= "\nContent-type: text/plain; charset=\"utf-8\"";`

and save this file in utf-8

Answer (score 0):

Try

htmlentities($_POST['message'])  instead only $_POST['message']

Comment: i tried it but now it does not work at all. I got no message when i tested it!

Answer (score 0):

Add `\nContent-type: text/plain; charset=\"utf-8\"\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit` to the end of your `$header` variable (you can do this by using the `.=` operator).

Cyrillic characters do not exist in plain ascii, so you need to use different character encoding.